# Is there software that can recognise which musical notes I am playing into my microphone - to help me practice music?

Tags: sound, music, software-recommendation

To help me practice music, I'd like to make a sound (hum, sing or whistle into my microphone) and have the corresponding note displayed on screen. A program that gives feedback live (while I play) would be ideal, but giving feedback on a recording would also be acceptable.

Comment: If I can't find anything suitable I may try code something in my free time. I imagine I would have to do some research on gstreamer and music theory.

Comment: I don't know anything about music, but I came across this [link](http://open-tube.com/15-awesome-free-and-open-source-audio-applications-list) I don't know if you will find anything useful there, but thought I would pass it on to you.

Answer (score 5):

I've been looking for a program like this for quite some time. I would love
a program that you can hum and it will translate it into musical notation. 
But for the time I user a tuner program on my cellphone. There are
several for linux listed in freshmeat so check them out, for something
that works for you.

http://freshmeat.net/search?page=1&q=tuner&submit=Search&with=66&without=

Answer (score 3):

Use [tonescope.net](https://tonescope.net). Hate to reply to a necro thread, but just in case someone stumbles upon this and wants the answer, I made a website recently for just that. It uses the sound from your microphone to return note name, octave and pitch in real time. Hope you find it useful!

Comment: I think the term "necro thread" is very destructive. Many threads have been relevant for decades. Please don't push yourself into the pseudo-limitations.

Answer (score 2):

For music practice CANTA-game.org is reputed to run in Linux and will pick up acoustic instrument via microphone and compare in real time to your previously input song note for note and give an instant colour-coded comparative result on screen.